# Find the version of array which elements sum is closest to zero when you can alter each element sign

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, combinations

Basically title, but I'll try to explain.

Imagine we have an array like `[2, 3, -4, 6, -2, -1]`

The goal is to find the version of this array when the sum of elements is closest to zero. The action you are allowed to do is change the sign of any element. So, for example the sum of a provided array is `4`, but we could change the sign of the first element to make an array look like `[-2, 3, -4, 6, -2, -1]` so that sum is now `0`

I couldn't find the way other than brute forcing so decided to ask somebody if you could think of maybe some way to optimize that process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are already a few dozen answers to this question on Stack Overflow, if you'd like to search for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could not find another way than brute forcing since this is a `NP-Complete` problem. It is equivalent to the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) where you need to split the array to two sets with equal sum. Until someone will prove or dispute the `P=NP` problem it means for you that the time complexity will be higher than `2^n` (where `n` is the number of elements in your set).

The problems are equivalent since if you find two sets (a partition) with equal sum that than you can put the sign on every element in the first set and if you can find signs like that than they define two sets with equal sum (We have actually performed a [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)) here).

There are some pseudo-polynomial algorithms so if you can bound the highest number than you can use them. You can also use some approximation algorithms. All of the information is in the wikipedia page of the partition problem.

Good luck.